# How to estimate the $n$-th derivative of a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, programming

How can I compute the $n$-th derivative of a $C^n$ function evaluated at some point $x_0$? In other words, how can I calculate $f^{(n)}(x_0)$?

I tried by using
$$f(x_0)\approx\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {n}{k}\frac{(-1)^kf\left(x_0+(n−2k)h\right)}{(2h)^n}$$
but I did not get good results. Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific; the answer depends a lot on what you're trying to do and what kind of function we're talking about. It'd probably help to say more on what you mean by "did not get good results" - what exactly did you do and why was it not satisfactory?

Comment: I wanted to get the coefficients of the Taylor polynomial for a well-defined function like $\sin x$. What I did was to code the sum in Fortran, but the coefficients did not match the true ones.

Comment: Oh, I think you might be missing a factor of $\frac{1}{(2h)^n}$ in the expression. That'd probably fix it as long as $h$ is reasonably small. (If not there are more interesting problems that can arise with numerical stability and whatnot - but there's a good chance correcting the missing factor will fix it)